# How to add more functions to buildt in classes/types as int, double, std::string etc

Tags: c++, class

You probably know that datatypes as `std::string` have some functions in it.
For example `std::string.substr()`.
I want to know, is there a way that i can add more funcionts to those types?
For example:

```
int a = 42;
a.isLife(); // a function that returns true if a is 42
```

But `isLife()` doesn't exist right?
Is there a way i can add it?

Comment: C++ doesn't have extension methods, like C# does.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: That, and in C++ these built-in types are shared with C. They don't have any member functions at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's not possible in C++. In C++ you write `isLife(a)` instead.

Comment: Thank you, but can i somehow add to std::string, because it is 100% made in C++ and not stolen from C?

Comment: what is a "free function"? Is it just like a normal function that we define as "type name(arguments)  {})?

Comment: @SonicAsF: A free function is a function that's declared at namespace scope, i.e. not a class member. This includes functions in the global namespace. For example, `int main()` is a free function, and so is `std::swap<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible.  You either have to write your own type that behaves like and `int` and you provide a `isLife` member function or you provide a free function `isLife` that takes an `int`

There [was a proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4165.pdf) to have a universal call syntax where `foo.bar()` would call `bar(foo)` is `bar` is actually a free fucntion but it was rejected.  Something else could come up or you could try proposing your own.

---

Do note that it is also illegal (per the standard) to add member functions to standard library types.  You can add free functions but you are not allowed to modify the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no way to do so.**

Primitive types are primitive, they don't have operator `.`available. Primitive types *are not classes*.

You also cannot append anything to a defined class. Once it's defined, it's complete. Otherwise, compiler wouldn't be able to use this class - what if there was one use of a non-changed class, then someone adds something to this class and uses this class. Which version is now used?

In theory, you could edit system headers like `<string>`, but that's **very** theoretical. It's against the standard and no compiler supports it AFAIK.

Comment: GCC is Open Source, and so is `libstdc++`. You may edit them, legally. But this is basically building your own C++ compiler. You're now responsible for making everything work.

Comment: To clarify: you mean “legally” as in “court of law”. Once you change the API of `std` types it’s not legal standard C++.

Comment: @Ben: I meant it in both senses of the word. Implementations **are** allowed to add methods to classes, as extensions. Your own libstdc++-derived implementation is no exception to this rule. But relying on extensions is of course unportable, and relying on your own extensions doubly so..

Answer (score 0):

@SonicAsF, you cannot/should not. @MSalters have the correct answer. That is how C++ intends you to extend classes. This is why `std::begin`, `std::end`, and `std::swap` are what they are. This is also why argument-dependent (“Koenig”) lookup works the way it does: if you have a class `C` in a namespace `NS` and a function `void NS::f(const NS::C&)`, if you have `NS::C c;` you can call `f(c);` unqualified outside `NS`. Philosophically, C++ considers `f` to be a part of `C`’s interface.

Comment: I considered saying something about this, but the fundamental types do not have associated namespaces.